# How can I go about creating a saving system for a text based adventure game in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and was trying to create a text based adventure game. I want to implement a saving system where players are able to save anytime during the game, and continue the story from where they left off. This would also have to save important relevant variables. I have thought about creating a save function like this:

```
 def save():
    pickle.dump(race,open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\race.dat','wb'))
    print("Saved!")
    return
```

This would work for variables that will exist throughout the story permanently, like gold, health etc, but this doesn't work for progress through the story. If I want the player to be able to continue the story where they left off how could I do that? Thankyou!

By progress through the story I mean something like this,:

```
    import pickle
import os
#defining save, add any variables to this that you want to save following the same format
def save():
    pickle.dump(race,open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\race.dat','wb'))
    print("Saved!")
    return
#checking if a save file already exists
race_exist=os.path.isfile(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\race.dat')
#if the save file exists, start from here
if race_exist==True:
    race=pickle.load(open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\race.dat','rb'))
    if race=='human':
        direction=input("You arrive at a crossroads during your travel, would you like to go left or right")
        if direction=='save':
            save()
    else:print('someone stabbed you because theyre racist.')
#if save file does not exist, start from here:
elif race_exist==False:
    race=input("Are you an orc or human?")
    pickle.dump(race,open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test\race.dat','wb'))
    if race=='orc':
        print("People dislike orcs, you get stabbed during your sleep and die!")
    elif race=='human':
        direction=input("You arrive at a crossroads during your travel, would you like to go left or right")
        if direction=='save':
            save()
```

here progress throughout the story is like, them coming to crossroads, deciding where to go etc, For example, if the player decides to go left, then saves the game, When he comes back I want him to be able to continue the story from where he left off (going left on the crossroads) rather than have to start all the way back choosing his race and direction again. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. As we don't know how you handle the "process through the story", it might be hard for us to help you. Please elaborate by editig your post.

Comment: use a dict for game variables, and save the dict using pickl or json

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Hey! Thank you! I dont really understand what you mean, sorry! Im really new to python and programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) would be a good thing to use.

You can create one like so.

```py
events = {
    "first_crossing": false // choice made at first crossing
}
```

Next, check the variable for the data.

```py
        direction = events["first_crossing"]
        if !direction: # if direction has not been chosen
            direction=input("You arrive at a crossroads during your travel, would you like to go left or right")
```

Then, update the event if the value changes.

```py
events["first_direction"] = direction
```

There are many types of data you could store this way, for example.

```py
events = {
    "chapter1": {
        "completed_tutorial1": false,
        "completed_event1": fasle,
        ...
    },
   ...
}
```

Make sure to save this variable.

Comment: Thank you! I have a followup question: Using the method you said, I could save progress in the story, but for saving different variables like gold, health, etc what would be the best way? I imagine it would just be using pickle.dump(health,open(r'path/etc','wb) and then loading it on start? Thank you again!

Comment: You could use the same approach as above by making a `dictionary` called `stats`. `stats = {"health": 50, "gold": 126, etc...}` or you can save them individualy. I'd recommend grouping them into a dictionary though.

Comment: Hey! How exactly do I save the dictionary variables?
For example, after i chance completed_tutorial1 to True, how would I save that variable to be True forever, and not reset back to False when the game is opened next time?

Comment: By using `pickle` to save it to a file and reopen it once you start up the game again.

Comment: Yes! I just figured that out a moment before your reply! Thank you!!! I can finally start coding this dang game, your dictionary solution is working perfectly!